# Why is UWP TextBlock sealed?

Tags: uwp, textblock

Why is this class sealed?  This is a major headache and there's no practical benefit. Instead of having a nice clean design with a subclassed control like this:

```
<controls:DecimalBlock Content="{Binding Path=Quantity}" Format="#,##0"/>
```

I'm forced to litter my code with this abomination:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Quantity, Converter={StaticResource StringFormatter}, ConverterParameter=\{0:#\,##0\}}"/>
```

Comment: I would guess that it is due to textblock did a lot of things to increase the performance. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/text-block#performance-considerations).  And this line "The most important condition is that the fast path is used only when you set text by explicitly setting the Text property"

Comment: I've heard this argument before.  I've been developing in C# for almost 18 years and I still don't understand it.  Could you please hypothesis for me how sealing a class improves performance.  If you don't want the performance hit for making some method virtual, then don't make it virtual.  What excuse is there for sealing off the entire class?

Comment: Well. I can only guess that maybe this control is already lightweight enough and they don't want we to inherit from it. Or maybe there are some other reasons which are blackbox to us. Anyway, if there is a problem which has business impact please let me know, I will help to work with you on it.

Comment: Yes, I explained the problem.  This design decision forces me to litter my XAML code with hard-to-read controls for no describable engineering advantage.  The **TextBlock** was inheritable in WPF, so not only is the new UWP more difficult to read and support, I have to translate much of my old WPF code.  Sealed classes fly in the face of OOD, so there should be an **incontrovertible** reason for making a class sealed.

Comment: OK. So please add your uservoice to here https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform and share the link to us. I will also raise this from my internal channel. We may not able to get a reason right now but at least it's a start for this specific request.